C++ double type: is comparison by == valid if comparing against the previously set value
What I mean is: I have a situation that I have two fields in the structure of type double, where both may be set there through some evaluation, but in some situations the second of them can be equal to the first one, but when such a situation happens, it is simply assigning the second field to the value of the first one.
Now, to recognize that that was the case, I'm using the == operator to check if that has happened. The compiler (gcc) complains that this kind of comparison is unsafe. But if this results in false because the values are not exactly equal because of some small epsilon of difference, that's still acceptable (meaning, if they result not equal although the calculations that evaluate them separately should ship the same result). The only thing I need to detect through this comparison was that the second field was assigned a value directly taken from the first one.
Is the == operator used safely in such a situation, or should I really add some extra boolean field to record this and rely on this only?
Example:
double a, b;

a = calculate_A();
b = calculate_B();

if (a == b) // results false, although calculations should ship the same: THAT'S STILL OK.

a = calculate_A();
b = a;

if (a == b) // can I rely on that this results ALWAYS TRUE in this case?


What if the two values happen to be equal for reasons other than the reason you want to detect?

Assigning b to a and comparing them will always return true unless one or both of them are NaN.

Your first a == b may give a false result, but not always - because numerical errors (due to finite precision of floating point) may propagate through the two sets of calculations differently).   The second comparison will always give a true result, except for some specific cases (e.g. with IEEE floating point, assigning a NaN produces a NaN, and two NaNs always compare non-equal).   Without knowing what you're actually trying to achieve, however, it's impossible to say if it is worthwhile to use an additional boolean.

It's valid, but has a different purpose. With ==, you're comparing exact bitwise representations and you expressly want to get false if the bitwise representations aren't equal, which usually means you're not checking equality of results of calculations, but e.g. whether floating point data was correctly copied. Let's say you were serializing something and deserializing into 2 objects using different external methods, and want to write a unit test for comparing corresponding parts of those objects - you'd use exact equality.

== does exactly what it says it does: it tells you whether two floating-point values are equal. That misleading warning from gcc is because when you calculate the same thing in two different ways you might get slightly different results. That not "unsafe" in any reasonable sense of the word. You'd run into the same problem in integer math if you multiplied 2/3 by 4 and compared it with the result of multiplying 4/3 by 2. They're mathematically equivalent, but with finite data sizes they produce different results.

Ok, I think I have described in details what I'm trying to achieve. If I have two values that come out of two different calculations, and they happen to be physically equal, this is expected. If they should be equal, but they weren't physically equal due to precision issues, this is still acceptable. The only thing that must be certain is that the operator== yields true always when I assigned one variable to another (let's even say except the NaN case).

In a nutshell, a 64 bit double type has ~52 bits allocated for its precision, which equates to ~15/16 digits (depends on the architecture). If you exceed this precision, you are flooding the precision bits of the double causing you to be in an undefined territory where all bets are off (see below). This could be either implementation-defined or undefined. Unfortunately, I could not find anything specified in the C++ standard about how std::setprecision comes up with the additional numbers.

In this example the precision is accurate up until the 19th decimal point, but may be compiler dependent. Don’t trust this. Anything beyond the ~16th decimal place is not well-defined because it does not fit in memory.
The same principle applies with non-trivial conversions, such as converting a string to a double (see below).

In C++, a double conforms to the IEEE 754 binary64 format. This means that when two doubles of the same value are defined, ex. a = b = calcWhatever(), by design they will contain the exact same sequence of precision. If this was not well-defined, then defining two numbers in different parts/files of our programs would imply different numbers and that is not possible or sane (see below).
std::string a_str = "0.0003253";
std::string b_str = "0.0003253";
    
double a = stod(a_str);
double b = stod(b_str);
    
std::cout<< std::setprecision(30) << a <<std::endl;
std::cout<< std::setprecision(30) << b <<std::endl;

Output:
0.000325299999999999992373461710216
0.000325299999999999992373461710216

The doubles contain the same exact value. Although the precision is set to something that’s beyond the accepted limit, the compiler will comply with the IEEE format and define the same sequence of decimal points because it will see the first definition and reuse it.
AFAIK, the only way that two doubles won’t have the exact same precision is for the following reasons:

Each double is compiled by a different compiler on a different architecture.
Each double is a result of a mathematical operation that cannot be trivially optimized or cannot be evaluated at compile time or cannot fit exactly fit in a double. For example:


0.3   == 0.2 + 0.1       /* NOK */
0.001 == 1.0/1000        /* OK */
2.5   == 2.5 * (5.0/5.0) /* OK */


Each double is a result of non-trivial conversion, including casts, from different sized types. For example:


double to float /* imprecise */
string to double /* precise */

In your case, depending on the functions calculate_A and calculate_B ex. constexpr, the doubles might be well-defined, but it's a very high risk one that is not worth taking. The second case is always going to be well-defined and a == b shall always return true.

I'm not one of your down voters, but I would guess that happened because your answer does not address the question asked, which (as I understand it) is, if you perform an assignment of one double variable to another are the two variables guaranteed to be == afterwards.

That on copying a value, the == always yields true is alright.
Of course the comparison could also yield true when calculated.
I had some hesitance, as though for 64 bits floats, some internal operations can be done using extended floating point, 80 bits. On comparing 64 bits copied into 80 bits anything might happen. However then even the same data might not compare when using two registers. So == must work.
